# dyadically recursive matrices: Part II

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, sequences-and-series, determinants

We present some variation on [this MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/264753/dyadically-recursive-matrices-part-i) which is equally amusing to me.

Define the $2^{n-1}\times 2^{n-1}$ matrix $A_n$ recursively as follows: $A_1(a_1)=\begin{pmatrix} a_1\end{pmatrix}$ and
$$A_n(a_1,\dots,a_n)=\begin{pmatrix} A_{n-1}(a_1,\dots,a_{n-1})& a_nJ_{n-1}\\ -a_nJ_{n-1}&A_{n-1}(a_1,\dots,a_{n-1})
\end{pmatrix}.$$
Here $J_n$ is a $2^{n-1}\times 2^{n-1}$ matrix with $1$'s on the antidiagonal and zeros elsewhere.

*Example.* For $n=2$ and $n=3$, we have
$$A_2(a_1,a_2)=\begin{pmatrix} a_1&a_2\\-a_2&a_1\end{pmatrix}
\qquad\text{and} \qquad
A_3(a_1,a_2,a_3)=\begin{pmatrix} a_1&a_2&0&a_3\\-a_2&a_1&a_3&0\\0&-a_3&a_1&a_2\\-a_3&0&-a_2&a_1\end{pmatrix}.$$

> **Question.** Is there a closed (or interesting) formula for the determinant $\det(A_n)$?

Comment: Looks like $(a_1^2 + \ldots a_n^2)^{2^{n-1}}$.

Comment: That's what I am getting too. Perhaps we should seek for a proof then.

Comment: Well you surely mean $(a_1^2 + \ldots a_n^2)^{2^{n-\color{red}2}}$. :)

Comment: That's correct, Wolfgang.

Comment: Maybe you should index the rows and the columns of $A_n$ not by numbers from $1$ to $2^{n-1}$, but by length-$\left(n-1\right)$ bitstrings (which correspond to these numbers via base-$2$ representation). The entry in row $x_1x_2\cdots x_{n-1}$ and column $y_1y_2\cdots y_{n-1}$ is then obtained as follows: Let $k$ be the largest index such that $x_k = y_k$. (This is set to be $0$ if no such $k$ exists.) If some $i < k$ satisfies $x_i \neq y_i$, then the entry is $0$. If not, then the entry is $\left(-1\right)^{x_{k+1}} a_{n-k}$, where $x_n = 0$.

Comment: This also suggests a line of attack. If we can remove the annoying $\left(-1\right)^{x_{k+1}}$ factor, then we are left with a group determinant (for the group $\left(\mathbb{Z} / 2 \mathbb{Z}\right)^{n-1}$), because $k$ depends only on the entrywise XOR of $x_1 x_2 \cdots x_{n-1}$ and $y_1 y_2 \cdots y_{n-1}$.

Comment: These determinants look like norms of elements of some twisted kind of Cayley-Dickson construction...

Comment: Ah! There is a known trick that works for quaternions, and that also works here. Your matrices $A_n$ are "almost orthogonal": They satisfy $A_n \left(A_n\right)^T = \left(a_1^2+a_2^2+\cdots+a_n^2\right) I_{2^{n-1}}$. (You can prove this by induction, using the fact that $A_n J_n = J_n \left(A_n\right)^T$, which you can also prove by induction.) Taking determinants, we obtain $\left(\det\left(A_n\right)\right)^2 = \left(a_1^2+a_2^2+\cdots+a_n^2\right)^{2^{n-1}}$. Now, it ...

Comment: ... remains to take the square root. In order to make sure that the sign is right, argue about the evaluation at $a_2=a_3=\cdots=a_n=0$.

Comment: @darijgrinberg: Perhaps you like to make your comments into an answer.

Comment: @darijgrinberg: Can you give me some reference to what you mentioned as "known trick that works for quaterions"? I'm interested what you are doing in quaternions, Thanks.

Comment: @T.Amdeberhan: I wish I had the time to write the long-ish expository answer that this question deserves... As for your second question, see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/706513/calculating-the-determinant-gives-a2b2c2d22/706532 (Kaladin's proof is more complicated than necessary). I believe this matrix is something like a multiplication matrix by the quaternion $a+bi+cj+dk$, although I have not checked. The whole thing seems to be connected with the notion of a reduced norm in a central simple algebra, but I am not sure how far this connection is worth pursuing.

Answer (score 1):

Finally, here is an argument that I came up with.

We proceed with induction on $n$. The base case $n=2$ is obvious. So assume $n\geq3$.
Denote $\widehat{A_n}=A_nJ_n, \widehat{B_n}=B_nJ_n$ and let $I_n$ be the $2^{n-1}$-dimensional identity matrix.
It is immediate that
$$\widehat{A_n}=\begin{pmatrix} a_nI_{n-1}&\widehat{A}_{n-1}\\ \widehat{A}_{n-1}&-a_nI_{n-1} \end{pmatrix}.$$
An important difference surfaces: now the two bottom pair of block-matrices \it commute. \rm As a result, 
$$\begin{align} \det A_n&=\det J_n\det\widehat{A}_n=\det(-a_n^2I_{n-1}-\widehat{A}_n^2)=(-1)^{2^{n-2}}\det(a_nI_{n-1}\pm i\widehat{A}_n).\end{align}$$
The proof follows. $\square$